# The current request for action 'AdminManagement' on controller type 'AdminController' is ambiguous between the following action methods

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller, routes, attributerouting

```
[Route("admins")]
public ActionResult AdminManagement()
{
    EmployeeBuslayer lstEmp = new EmployeeBuslayer();
    AdminManamegemtModel comModel = new AdminManamegemtModel();
    comModel = lstEmp.GetAdminsWithRole;
    return View(comModel);
}

#region AdminMaster
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("AdminManagement")]
public ActionResult AdminManagementPost()
{
    string SearchText = Request.Form["Search"].ToString().ToLower();
    EmployeeBuslayer lstEmp = new EmployeeBuslayer();
    List<AdminMaster> dataEmployee = null;
    AdminManamegemtModel comModel = new AdminManamegemtModel();
    AdminManamegemtModel comModelfromDB = lstEmp.GetAdminsWithRole;
    dataEmployee = comModelfromDB.AdminMasterModel.Where(src => src.UserName.ToLower().Contains(SearchText) || src.EmailID.ToLower().Contains(SearchText)).ToList();
    comModel.AdminMasterModel = dataEmployee;
    comModel.AdminRoleMasterModel = comModelfromDB.AdminRoleMasterModel;
    return View("AdminManagement", comModel);

}
```

above two methods are for same view. and i have search button . when clicked on search it gives me below error.

> The current request for action 'AdminManagement' on controller type
>   'AdminController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AdminManagementPost() on type
>   MVCAdminDemo.Controllers.AdminController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   AdminManagement() on type MVCAdminDemo.Controllers.AdminController. I
>   can solve this error by removing ActionName from AdminManagementPost()
>   , but problem is URL changes and i dont want that . url shoud be
>   `http://localhost:52499/admin/admins`

AdminManagement() is Get method loads on load default

Answer (score 0):

I think action name does not matter here. As you have not specified any http verb for the first action method, it is considered as post. SO whenever you are trying to call this route, it is ambiguous as two action methods with verb post are available on same route. Decorate the first action method with [HttpGet] as it seems like a get action. sample code below:

```
    [Route("api/datasync/get")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOne()
    {
        return Ok(1);
    }

    [Route("api/datasync/get")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOnes()
    {
        return Ok(1);
    }
```

Comment: [Route("admins")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AdminManagement()
        {
//code
             

        }
 [Route("admins")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AdminManagementPost()
        {
//code
}
unfortunately not working 
on loads it working but when click on search post method , it shows no resource found .
i guess im using wrong method name ?
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AdminManagement", "Admin"))
            {
//html and button
}
https://jsfiddle.net/93t5xfg7/

Comment: The action name is AdminManagementPost right? Try changing it to AdminManagementPost  from AdminManagement in the Html.BeginForm, something like Html.BeginForm("AdminManagementPost ", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, null)

Comment: No bro its not working . well thanks ill try something . 
thanks for help . let me know if you get anything